# whats difference between ITNCM(Intelliden) and NETCOOL?

Tags: tivoli

I am new to NETCOOL and would like to comparison of NETCOOL with ITNCM(Intelliden).

what is major difference between these tools?

what is there in NETCOOL which Intelliden doesn't have ?

Is there any specific offering from IBM for NETCOOL ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say Netcool do you mean IBM® Tivoli® Netcool®/OMNIbus ?

ITNCM means IBM Tivoli Netcool Configuration Manager, and is used to manage configuration of network devices.

Tivoli Netcool have a series of product for network management and overview:

http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/category/network-management

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you are correct, ITNCM is a tools to manage network device configuration like firewall, switch, router, and etc. from all kind of network brand like Cisco, Juniper, Huawei, F5, Arista and etc.

Since all this network brand have different kind of configuration method, with ITNCM, you can open the GUI for the specific VTMOS (Vendor, Type, Model, OS) and your configuration will be done and send to device with just few clicks away.

Very powerful network configuration management tools.